# How to view folders with a large amount of files?

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, files, directory

I have folder, for example, with 1500000 images. I'm trying to open that folder to scroll through files, look at them and open some that I want to look at in image viewer. But when I open that folder it takes forever to load and display miniatures.

There's just "Loading..." sometimes without an end. Is there way to do so?

I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest splitting the files into separate subfolders using the command line before proceeding to view your files. Its unlikely that you will be able to productively view and browse the images until you reduce the file count per folder.

For example you can split the files by date. If there is a date stamp in the file, you can use a command like

```
cd /images-dir
mkdir 20150401
mv *20150401* 20150401
```

The `cd` command will take you to your image directory. The `mkdir` is to create a subfolder. The `mv` command is to perform the actual file move operation.